# Understanding the implementation of atomic multi-reader multi-writer register

Tags: java, multiprocessing, atomic, theory, multicore

I'm looking at the following implementation of an atomic multi-reader multi-writer register:

```
 public class AtomicMRMWRegister<T> implements Register<T>{
   private StampedValue<T>[] a_table; // array of atomic MRSW registers
   public AtomicMRMWRegister(int capacity, T init) {
     a_table = (StampedValue<T>[]) new StampedValue[capacity];
     StampedValue<T> value = new StampedValue<T>(init);
     for (int j = 0; j < a_table.length; j++) {
       a_table[j] = value;
     }
    }
   public void write(T value) {
     int me = ThreadID.get();
     StampedValue<T> max = StampedValue.MIN_VALUE;
     for (int i = 0; i < a_table.length; i++) {
       max = StampedValue.max(max, a_table[i]);
     }
     a_table[me] = new StampedValue(max.stamp + 1, value);
   }
   public T read() {
     StampedValue<T> max = StampedValue.MIN_VALUE;
     for (int i = 0; i < a_table.length; i++) {
       max = StampedValue.max(max, a_table[i]);
     }
     return max.value;
   }
 }

public class StampedValue<T> {
  public long stamp;
  public T value;
  // initial value with zero timestamp
  public StampedValue(T init) {
    stamp = 0;
    value = init;
  }
  // later values with timestamp provided
  public StampedValue(long stamp, T value) {
    stamp = stamp;
    value = value;
  }
  public static StampedValue max(StampedValue x, StampedValue y) {
    if (x.stamp > y.stamp) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return y;
    }
  }
  public static StampedValue MIN_VALUE = new StampedValue(null);
}
```

Taken from the textbook **The art of multiprocessor programming**: [source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=qGURkdAr42cC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=atomic%20mrmw%20register&source=bl&ots=BLvj-qbthE&sig=Lg8-nBmhxr5P37VPbGuKXsVtt90&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0wevsve3LAhVD-A4KHRmzDCkQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 86

What do they mean when they state that `a_table` is an atomic MRSW register? When its type is `StampedValue<T>`?

Comment: post your code not image of code.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu done. not my code though

Comment: adding your code actually gives people to copy from here and run in their environment, so that they can test their solution before posting it here.

Comment: if this code is meant to be multi-thread safe, it is failing horribly.

Comment: Is StampedValue defined in another part of the book? looks like it uses either StampedLock or AtomicStampedReference as a locking mechanism to be MRSW .

Comment: @CristianoFontes its defined a couple of pages beforehand. Its not using any additional protection, pretty much straightforward as much as I could understand

Comment: so, what exactly is your question here?

Comment: @jtahlborn why are they stating that this class is implementing an atomic MRMW register while it doesn't seem so to any innocent bystander?

Comment: @Mugen could post the code of that?

Comment: @CristianoFontes edited

Comment: i still don't understand your question.  are you trying to understand what an MRMW register is?  or if the code is implementing it correctly?  or something else...?  (the first question can be answered by google.  the second is "no", third...?)

Comment: @jtahlborn I meant the second - if the code is implementing it correctly. Apparently I was expecting too much from this book. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The comment says `a_table` is an “**array of** atomic MRSW registers”, not that “`a_table` *is* an atomic MRSW register”. That’s different. But besides, I don’t get the purpose of that thing. If we assume that it was thread safe, e.g. if `stamp` and `value` were declared `final` or `volatile`, I don’t see what it offers compared to a single shared variable with the same degree of safety, i.e. multiple threads can write to it and multiple threads can read from it. The degree of control ever the outcome is the same…